# Is there an Alternate for Where is Null using Where = Null?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If not, is there an alternate way to switch through SELECT statements using a CASE or IF/THEN identifier WITHOUT putting the statement in a scalar variable first?

Is there a way to format this without using IS and using an = sign for it to work?

```
    SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID = Null
```

Comment: When you need to check for NULL, the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` is the **only valid** way to go

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide more information.

Comment: This is a bit abstract, a schema and some data, with desired output, would help.

Comment: You can also use the IsNull(col, value) function, where value will be returned if the column is null. This works in CASE statements too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. NULL isn't a value. Think of NULL as a condition, with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` is testing for this condition.

In this example you can test for the actual value, or lack of value represented by a conditon

```
WHERE
   (X IS NULL OR X = @X)
```

OR

```
WHERE
  (@X IS NULL OR X = @X)
```

Or test for your definite conditions first:

```
WHERE
    CASE X
      WHEN 1 THEN
      WHEN 2 THEN
      ELSE --  includes NULL
   END = ...
```

Your question is abstract so hard to give a more precise answer.

For example, are you having problems with NOT IN and NULL? If so, use NOT EXISTS.